# Getting "not eligible to build" error when updating iPad 2 to 4.3.3

Tags: mac, applications, data-synchronization, ipad

I'm trying to update my iPad 2 firmware to 4.3.3 but iTunes is giving me a "not eligible to build" error. I have tried editing my host files, but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Ton. We try to have very objective, answerable questions here. Would you edit this to focus on either 4.3.3 firmware or OSX upgrade issues? Both are awesome questions, but together, not so useful to others and hard to answer well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download 4.3.5 instead
2. Update your Java by going to software update. Which OS x version did you have previously?